# Prestashop 8 hook after Guest to Customer conversion

Tags: prestashop, hook, prestashop-modules

in my module I use `hookActionObjectCustomerUpdateAfter()` it works fine only when customer create new account or update exisiting one, but not in case when user with GUEST account create account.

In that specific scennario after `hookActionObjectCustomerUpdateAfter()` is runing method `CustomerPersister::update()` from classes/form/CustomerPersister.php so some of my changes are overrided.

What is best option to run my code after changing guest to customer account?

Comment: Did you try actionObjectCustomerAddAfter? Prestashop when promoting a guest to customer creates a new entry in ps_customer tabel, probably will trigger that hook in the creation. Let me know.

Comment: Yes I tried that same effect like before.

Comment: Maybe actionObjectCustomerPersisterAddAfter? I don't know if it exists and cannot test it right now but if CustomerPersister is an object, following PS logic, it could work.